# Information in the console on hover

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, console

Please, help me :)
I would like to see the information in the console Google Chrome when I hover over an object

It should be like this:
[image: It should be like this:]
But I see only that (when I hover on object I can't see nothing) [!But I see only that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmtrF.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmtrF.jpg)
Where should I check my settings?

Comment: Does your program stop at breakpoints?

Comment: @norysoft Yes, it is